# /boot symlinks do not match current kernel version

Tags: centos, boot, linux-kernel

I'm a bit puzzled on the following:

I have a multi-kernel system, with a default one set by `grub.conf`, which is the 3.6 ; what I don't understand is why when I list the files in `/boot/` I see the kernel symlinks (`vmlinuz` and `System.map`) are pointing to another version than the current one!? That doesn't make much sense.

```
# uname -r
3.6.11.5-rt37.55.el6rt.x86_64

# ll /boot/
total 175180
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   106312 Dec 16  2014 config-2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   129027 Feb 10 11:35 config-3.14.58-rt59
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   115846 Sep 17  2013 config-3.6.11.5-rt37.55.el6rt.x86_64
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root     4096 Oct 27 15:15 efi
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root     4096 Feb 10 11:27 grub
-rw-------. 1 root root 18799747 Oct 27 15:16 initramfs-2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64.img
-rw-------  1 root root  6903796 Feb 10 11:27 initramfs-3.14.58-rt59.img
-rw-------  1 root root 15747530 Feb  8 12:32 initramfs-3.6.11.5-rt37.55.el6rt.x86_64.img
-rw-------. 1 root root  4763702 Oct 27 15:33 initrd-2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64kdump.img
drwx------. 2 root root    16384 Oct 27 15:11 lost+found
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   200269 Dec 16  2014 symvers-2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64.gz
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       29 Feb 10 11:26 System.map -> /boot/System.map-3.14.58-rt59
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  2544888 Dec 16  2014 System.map-2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2459564 Feb 10 11:26 System.map-3.14.58-rt59
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2176146 Sep 17  2013 System.map-3.6.11.5-rt37.55.el6rt.x86_64
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       26 Feb 10 11:26 vmlinuz -> /boot/vmlinuz-3.14.58-rt59
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  4152944 Dec 16  2014 vmlinuz-2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  4715088 Feb 10 11:26 vmlinuz-3.14.58-rt59
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4198832 Sep 17  2013 vmlinuz-3.6.11.5-rt37.55.el6rt.x86_64
#
```

Answer (score 1):

The kernel symlinks pointing to a new kernel rather the one that you are running means that you have compiled/installed a new kernel.

I would also start deleting old kernel versions, namely the 2.6.32 that you have installed, as often there are size limits in the /boot partition.

You have to edit grub; I do recommend that the default grub boot points to the symlinks, whereas the alternate boots point to specific kernels.

You may need to run this command to update grub.

```
sudo update-grub
```

If it indeed updates grub, then run:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Comment: The screen output in the question was taken after a reboot. I had installed kernel 3.6 form a yum repo, but the 3.14 was recompiled and installed directly on the machine.

Comment: If you install a kernel by hand, then grub wont be changed automatically and you still have not edited grub, obviously the old kernel will still be booting. I will change the answer then.